# Beta-diversity among grids

Tags: coordinate-system, r, geocoding

I started a new project in which I'm be measuring beta diversity between grids. The most appropriate metric to use is the Bray-Curtis dissimilarity index. I can perform calculations between raster files that contain a single data type (i.e. species richness or abundance), but I haven't been able to find a package or any script in R I can use to perform more complex calculations, as a dissimilarity index in which two different data are used from each grid (i.e. species richness or abundance).
Any ideas or guidance?

Comment: Are you wanting global or local (focal) measures? Please provide some additional information on what your expected output would look like and what you have tried thus far.

Comment: Good afternoon,